# How to avoid calculating the same expression several times in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

In following SQL the SUM(i) and SUM(y) is calculated more then once:

```
SELECT
    IF(SUM(i) > 3000, 3000, SUM(i)) AS total_x,
    CASE 
       WHEN SUM(y) > 3000 THEN 3000
       WHEN SUM(y) < 0 THEN 0
       ELSE SUM(y)
    END AS total_y
FROM t
```

Is it any way to calculate SUM(i) and SUM(y) just once (for better performance) or SQL engine is smart enough to optimize it internally without the human intervention?

My database engine in Hive, but the question can be applied to any SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't really worry about it, but you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT LEAST(total_i, 3000),
       GREATEST(LEAST(total_y, 3000), 0) as total_y
FROM (SELECT SUM(i) as total_i, SUM(y) as total_y
      FROM t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT SUM(i) AS SUM_I, SUM(y) AS SUM_Y
             FROM t)
SELECT
    IF(SUM_I > 3000, 3000, SUM_I) AS total_x,
    CASE 
       WHEN SUM_Y > 3000 THEN 3000
       WHEN SUM_Y < 0 THEN 0
       ELSE SUM_Y
    END AS total_y
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case of Hive:

1. Identical aggregation within the same `select` clause will be evaluated just once.
2. CTE is just a syntax sugar. They are relocated to where they are referred to in the form of subqueries. Thus CTE may be eveluated more than once. Turn on the parallel execution flag `hive.exec.parallel` to reduce time overhead.